# Java & Akka: Creating an actor B from actor A

Tags: java, akka

I'm trying to understand how an Actor A can generate (one or many) Actor(s) B.
I already have class "mater" that creates and activates Actor A.
Do I need to create something like that in the A actor:

```
ActorSystem system = ActorSystem.create("my-name");
ActorRef actorB = system.actorOf(Props.create(ActorB.class));

actorB.tell("do something that A says", ActorRef.noSender());
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Actors are created in a tree hierarchy that resembles a FileSystem.

If you want your actor B to exist at the top level (i.e. a child of system/user), you create it with:

```
ActorRef actorB = system.actorOf(Props.create(ActorB.class, ActorB::new));
```

if you want, from inside actor A, to create B as a child of A, you execute the same method on the context:

```
ActorRef actorB = getContext().actorOf(Props.create(ActorB.class, ActorB::new));
```

Once you have an actorRef, you can use it normally to tell and ask stuff.